# issue with creating new columns in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, quantitative-finance

I help with adding the below columns to a data frame, any guidance is much appreciated.I created the variable: no_outlier_pe_go `['industry_marketCap']= _outlier_pe_g.groupby('industry')['marketCap'].transform('sum')` but keep getting errors once I try to create the subsequent columns, (instructions and screenshot below).

[image: Warning]

Use this variable to create an industry PE as a marketCap weighted PE of stocks in the industry and name it `'ind_pe'`. (Hint: you need a column that reflect the marketCap weight of each stock in the industry, `'wt_in_industry'`, another column for the product of trailingPE by its industry weight and name it pe_ind_wt. Use the transform method on the latter variable to create ind_pe as the sums to pe_ind_wt ).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you created `no_outlier_pe_g` as a copy of another `DataFrame`. You can check so by `df._is_copy`, as shown here:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["SWN US EQUITY", "Oil & Gas E & P", 1.610607e09],
        ["AMCR US EQUITY", "Packaging & Containers", 1.762973e10],
    ],
    columns=["symbol", "industry", "marketCap"],
)

# create a copy
no_outlier_pe_g = df.iloc[0:, :]

# ...
df2 = no_outlier_pe_g

no_outlier_pe_g["industry_marketCap"] = no_outlier_pe_g.groupby("industry")[
    "marketCap"
].transform("sum")

# check if copy
print(df2._is_copy)
```

Technically, it's just a warning not an error. The `SettingWithCopyWarning` warns you that you work on a copy of the `DataFrame`, which leaves the original `DataFrame` unaltered and might lead to unexpected results e.g. with chained operations. It has been discussed extensively in [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy).

In your use case it's fine, if you are aware of the possible inconsistencies.